# C# WPF Data Binding CheckBoxes based on ComboBox Selection in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am currently learning the MVVM design pattern for WPF and I would like to bind my CheckBoxes based on the SelectedItem of my ComboBox which is data binded to a Dictionary where the key is my device serial number and the value is a ViewModel for that device.

[image]

Ideally, my SelectedItem should be the value which is IOBoardViewModel.

```
<ComboBox Name="io_boards_list" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding IOBoards}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="361,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="657" Height="35"/>
```

This is where I am most unclear: how to bind these bool values in my IOBoard Model.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{ Binding Value.io_board.s0 }" Content="Input 0" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Height="15"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{ Binding Value.io_board.s1 }" Content="Input 1" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="36" Height="15"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{ Binding Value.io_board.s2 }" Content="Input 2" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="63" Height="15"/>
```

In my IOBoardViewModel I refer to the actual Model which is where I hold my bool value.

```
        public Dictionary<string, IIOBoardViewModel> IOBoards { get; private set; }

        public FullIOBoard io_board
        {
            get { return _io_board; }
        }
```

Here is a snippet from my IOBoard Model:

```
        public bool s0
        {
            get
            {
                return _s0;
            }
            set
            {
                _s0 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("s0");
            }
        }

        public bool s1
        {
            get
            {
                return _s1;
            }
            set
            {
                _s1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("s1");
            }
        }

        public bool s2
        {
            get
            {
                return _s2;
            }
            set
            {
                _s2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("s2");
            }
        }
```

I would like to know if I have the right idea on how to bind the data together in the MVVM pattern, and if not, I would greatly appreciate insights or advice.

**UPDATE:**
I have thought of a method that I could use where I bind the SelectedItem of the ComboBox (which would be the Dictionary's identifying serial number to a variable in my ViewModel):

```
public string SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedItem;
            }
            set
            {
                _SelectedItem = value;
            }
        }
```

Now I believe I should bind my IsChecked for the CheckBox to

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{ Binding IOBoards[SelectedItem].s0 }" Content="Input 0" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Height="15"/>
```

However I am still unable to get the checkbox to update even though I've hardcoded one of the signals to always be true:

```
_io_board.s0 = true;
_io_board.s1 = (inputSignal & 0x02) == 0x02;
```

Comment: Do you really need a dictionary? What happens when you add an IO board? Add the serial number to your IO board. Use SelectedItem binding instead of selectedvaluepath. Then you can Bind check box to SelectedItem in your view model like this {Binding SelectedIOBoard.s0} and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind directly to SelectedItem of ComboBox by referring to it by name:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{ Binding SelectedItem.Value.io_board.s0, ElementName=io_boards_list }"
```

Comment: Incredible! That was exactly what I was looking for. I had somewhat solved the issue yesterday in a very inefficient way but your solution brought my CPU usage from 18-20% to 1-3%.